# Why are empty arrays being hidden when outputting them as XML?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, hidden

I'm trying to have PHP convert nested arrays into an XML document. I've been unable to troubleshoot why arrays with no children are being hidden from the XML output entirely; I want them to show up as having no children in XML too.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
private function response_xml_encode($node, $data)
{
  if ($node == null) return false;
  if (!is_array($data)) return false;
  foreach ($data as $key => $value)
  {
    if (is_array($value) && !$this->response_xml_encode_assocarray($value))
    {
      foreach ($value as $val)
        $node->addChild($key, htmlentities($val));
    }
    else if (is_array($value))
    {
      $this->response_xml_encode($node->addChild($key), $value);
    }
    else if (!$this->response_xml_encode_validkey($key))
    {
      $subnode = $node->addChild($node->getName(), htmlentities($value));
      $subnode->addAttribute('keyinvalid', 'true');
      $subnode->addAttribute('key', htmlentities($key));
    }
    else
    {
      $node->addChild($key, htmlentities($value));
    }
  }
}

private function response_xml_encode_assocarray($arr)
{
  // Let's us know if this array has associative key value pairs, or if it has numeric key value pairs
  // Returns TRUE if this array has any non-numeric key in it
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
  {
    if (!is_numeric($key)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

private function response_xml_encode_validkey($key)
{
  if (strpos('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_', substr($key, 0, 1)) === false) return false;
  return (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z_-]/s', $key) === 0);
}
```

I then call it using:

```
$response = array(
  'result' => 0,
  'message' => 'Success.',
  'function' => 'test',
  'data' => array(
    'GET'  => $_GET,
    'POST' => $_POST,
    'foo'  => array(
      'bar' => array(
        'bad' => array(
          'wolf' => array(
            'some_value' => 'testtesttest'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
$root = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response/>');
$this->response_xml_encode($root, $response);
return $root->asXML();
```

Note that `$_GET` and `$_POST` are empty arrays.

The following is what gets returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result>0</result>
  <message>Success.</message>
  <function>test</function>
  <data>
    <foo>
      <bar>
        <bad>
          <wolf>
            <some_value>testtesttest</some_value>
          </wolf>
        </bad>
      </bar>
    </foo>
  </data>
</response>
```

But what's expected is for it to show `<GET/>` and `<POST/>` before it shows `<foo>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result>0</result>
  <message>Success.</message>
  <function>test</function>
  <data>
    <GET/>
    <POST/>
    <foo>
      <bar>
        <bad>
          <wolf>
            <some_value>testtesttest</some_value>
          </wolf>
        </bad>
      </bar>
    </foo>
  </data>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put below code snippet at the starting for your `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{    
   if(array_key_exists($key, $data) && empty($value))
   {
       $node->addChild($key, "");
   }
   //your other code goes here
}
```

Above code will output your desired output like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <result>
    </result>
    <message>Success.</message>
    <function>test</function>
    <data>
        <GET>
        </GET>
        <POST>
        </POST>
        <foo>
            <bar>
                <bad>
                    <wolf>
                        <some_value>test test test</some_value>
                    </wolf>
                </bad>
            </bar>
        </foo>
    </data>
</response>
```

I had taken your code for sample and executed it by creating a class. So this should be working for you also.

Comment: This worked almost as expected. I took this and changed it so that it's at the else{} part of the if block:

    else
    {
      if (!array_key_exists($key, $data))
        $node->addChild($key, '');
      else
        $node->addChild($key, htmlentities($value));
    }

This works as I need it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that I also added

    if (array_key_exists($key, $data) && is_array($value) && count($value) == 0)
      $node->addChild($key);

to the beginning of the first foreach() loop.